# Docker client on WSL cannot connect to Docker for Windows

Tags: windows-10, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I have docker set up on my Windows machine with WSL like this: 
(similar to what's described here https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/5eggwo/running_docker_on_windows_subsystem_for_linux_wsl/)

- Installed Docker for Windows
- Installed the docker client inside WSL
- `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375`

However, when I run `docker ps`, I get this error:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`

I know that docker is running, and if can get `docker.exe ps` ok from the Windows CMD.

I had this working before, but it doesn't seem to work now. I have updated the Docker for Windows app to the latest version, and restarted my machine a couple times.

Does anyone knows if there's something I could try?

Comment: 'docker run -it -v c:/Users:/users ubuntu bash' should be used

Comment: Any sucess? I got same problem.

Comment: Maybe docker is running on different port or it's not exposed, you can check this in docker desktop settings.